# Azure database performance recommendations getting 404 responses

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to apply database Performance recommendations from Azure portal, but they don'r seem to work.

Inspecting the console in Chrome developer tools shows the following error messages when trying to load this resource:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/Default-SQL-WestEurope/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/DB_SERVER_NAME/databases/DB_NAME/advisors/CreateIndex/recommendedActions/SOME_INDEX_NAME?api-version=2015-05-01-preview

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I'm also getting 404 for this URL:
https://management.azure.com/api/invoke

I did upgrade the DB a few days ago, but I'm quite sure that these messages also appeared before the upgrade.

What can cause this and how can it be solved?

Comment: Strange,i never faced those issues.Can you raise a ticket with azure team and share the update here?

Comment: I didn't face any of these issues before, and I did use database Performance recommendations.

Comment: Can you share step by step of what you are trying to do along with screenshots

Comment: "To submit a technical support request for this subscription, you must upgrade to a paid support plan. To upgrade or explore other support options, see the info to the right." - I think it's quite absurd.